# How to refresh page when clicking on a route

Tags: angular

Let's say I'm in the mobile view and I'm at the bottom of the document window and I click a hyperlink there. I'm routed to the next view, however the view remains at the top of the page. I would like it to be at the top. I have tried using `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` during `ngOnInit();` However, it's slow and the user has to wait until the scroll is complete, the process is noticeably visible. If I wasn't using a SPA, navigation would be near instant. Seems to me there has to be a better way.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried hash routing?  It is were you navigate to a specific bookmark on a SPA by using a hash or bookmark.

From the angular docs,
https://angular.io/guide/router#locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles , the nav link would be:

```
localhost:3002/src/#/crisis-center/
```

Where crisis-center is the hash URL.

Comment: I need to use the "HTML5 pushState" style just like the first link you shared as I do some SSR. However, I couldn't get this to work using the [routerLink] attribute as it kept converting my hash into %23 for some reason. However I removed routerLink and just went with a regular href attribute and it does accomplish what I was looking for. However, it seems like there should be a "angular" way of doing this?

Comment: 23 is the hex for `#`

If you're navigating to a new page, using hash routing, and pushState, you may be able to decode the hex back to a hash to 're-enable' hash routing.

Either way, glad you found a solution!

Comment: I spoke to soon, once compiled for prod and deployed, it no longer worked.